# Call specific number if NSDictionary doesn't match

Tags: iphone, nsdictionary, cllocationmanager

I'm developing an application that makes the user call a specific number depending on their current position using NSDictionary. This position is displayed on a label. Now, if the user is in a position that is not included in the NSDictionary, it calls "6588". How do I change that number to a number of my choice?

```
placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
_addressLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
                             placemark.thoroughfare, placemark.subThoroughfare,
                             placemark.postalCode, placemark.locality,
                             placemark.administrativeArea,
                             placemark.country];

- (IBAction)phone { [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:%@"]];
 NSDictionary *localityToPhoneNumber = @{@"London": @"123456",};

NSString *phoneNumber = [localityToPhoneNumber objectForKey:placemark.locality];
NSString *tel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", phoneNumber];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:tel]];
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Is that specific number fixed for all other locality which wont be there in NSDictionary for eg: {US, 6588} and {India, 6588}???

Comment: I don't know where 6588 comes from, but it's been like that from at least three different european countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check is the key in the dictionary exists and if it doesn't exist you can call the default number, which is in your case 6588.

Something like this:

```
if (![localityToPhoneNumber objectForKey:placemark.locality]) {
    // Call default number
} else {
    // Call the number for the locality
}
```